# Html.BeginForm Route Values including Form Radio Button result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, html.beginform, routevalues

I have asked a couple of questions over the last couple of days, that probably did not get answered because it might have been to broad.  After some research, I may have narrowed it down a little bit.

I am wondering if there is a way that I can use the Html.BeginForm(action,controller,routeValues) overload of Begin form to pass in RadioButton results (ie, the user has clicked one of the two choices).  I need that value passed into the query string so that my action can handle it.  My action takes two parameters, and so far I can only figure out how to get one of those values into the action.  Here is some example code...

```
<%Html.BeginForm("TemplateInfo","PatientACO",new { PopulationID = ViewData["POPULATIONID"], ActiveAll = "1"});        
%><input type="submit" value="Refresh" id="test" /><%
%></div>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Note, I am setting my ActiveAll attribute, auto Magically.  I need it set dynamically.  IE, it needs to be set by the user.  Because that particular action takes two parameters.  Need to figure out a way to get that dynamic value into that action?  I am hoping that routeValue dictionaries, or routValues in general will help me figure out a way to get this done.

If you have any idea's how to do this I would really appreciate this.

***UPDATE***

I also wanted to mention that I don't want to change the controller to accept FormCollections, because this action is called by other methods and views.  Any ideas?

***UPDATE 2***

Ok, with a little more research, I guess what I am trying to figure out is, how can I get the Form value of the Radio Button in the view so that I can then add it to a RouteValueDictionary or something...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass the selected values into a query string.

As long as the radio buttons have names equal to the variables you have in your controller action, MVC will bind the form values to the variables in your action.

In your example, if your form has a radio button list with the name `ActionAll`, and two radio buttons with values of `true` and `false`, then if your controller action has a boolean variable named `ActionAll`, the results of your radio button list selection will be bound to your controller action's ActionAll variable.

**UPDATE**

Based upon the information you provided, if your action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TemplateInfo(bool ActionAll, ... )
```

Then you can pass the ActionAll variable from a button list in your view with the following:

```
<input type="radio" value="true" id="ActionAll" name="ActionAll" /> All
<input type="radio" value="false" selected="selected" id="ActionAll" name="ActionAll" /> Not All
```

If you set a breakpoint in your action, you will see that ActionAll has been set based on the selected radio button in the list.  If ActionAll is not a boolean, adjust your list accordingly, to pass the correct type of value for binding to ActionAll.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I am pretty sure it doesn't work that way, as I ran into many errors attempting it that way.  I won't claim to know it all here, but there is a reason I have been searching in vain for a way to get it in there.  Anyway, I changed up my code to disinclude that code and reworked it abit.  if you clariy your answer a little more, I will mark this question as answered.